# Laravel queues not working without php artisan queue:work command

Tags: php, laravel, queue

My queue is working perfectly, when i run the following command `php artisan queue:work`
I’m using database as a QUEUE_DRIVER. On the server i don’t run the above command every-time.

for eg:

In schedule we have to run the command  `php artisan schedule:work`. In this case on server we register this in cronetab like this:

`* * * * * php /path/of/the/project/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Then we don’t have to run schedule work command again and again.

Is something also for queue. So we don’t have to run `php artisan queue:work` again and again. Also i don’t want to change the driver.

Comment: Does your crontab working on the server can you check?

Comment: yes cron is working perfectly

Comment: @CodyBrew did you add item to `schedule` method in `Console/Kernel.php` like this `$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyMinute();` ?

Comment: @maximkou haven’t register queue work command in the kernel, but i have registered my custom commands.

Comment: so, you need to do it.

Comment: But keep in mind about that: `queue:work` by default is a daemon, so if you start this workers every minute by cron - you have many worker processes after some time.

To prevent this, you can set `--max-time=60` argument, for example (worker stops after 60 sec and new worker is started every minute), example `$schedule->command('schedule:work --max-time=60')->everyMinute();`

Comment: ok i’ll try this.

Comment: In fact, run queue workers using cron is a bad idea. Better solution is use supervisor for this, how it recommends laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: @CodyBrew did you change the correct path here? /path/of/the/project/artisan also did you try to run the command on the server?  php /path/of/the/project/artisan schedule:run

Comment: @AhmedHassan Yes, my scheduler is working fine on server